# Why are the animations produced by the transformr package not displaying right?

Tags: r

I'm trying to learn to use transformr package in RStudio (version 2023.12.0+369), but when I run the very first example given in the [documentation](https://github.com/thomasp85/transformr), it only outputs a list of images rather than an animated gif.

```
library(transformr)
library(tweenr)
library(ggplot2)
polyplot <- function(data) {
  p <- ggplot(data) + 
    geom_polygon(aes(x, y, group = id, fill = col)) +
    scale_fill_identity() +
    coord_fixed(xlim = c(-1.5, 1.5), ylim = c(-1.5, 1.5))
  plot(p)
}

star <- poly_star()
star$col <- 'steelblue'
circles <- poly_circles()
circles$col <- c('forestgreen', 'firebrick', 'goldenrod')[circles$id]

animation <- tween_polygon(star, circles, 'cubic-in-out', 40, id) %>% 
  keep_state(10)

ani <- lapply(split(animation, animation$.frame), polyplot)
```

I've tried finding other ways to convert what I get into a gif and render it but I can't seem to find anything that works properly for that either. Closest I've gotten is saveGIF() which can create a gif using lapply(split(animation, animation$.frame), polyplot) as its expr argument but that only saves the gif to my computer rather than rendering it in RStudio, and loading the gif in again to display it seems horribly inefficient

```
saveGIF({
  lapply(split(animation, animation$.frame), polyplot)
}, interval = .05, movie.name="test.gif")
```

Comment: Have you considered `gganimate` ?